# Sharing data between HtmlHelpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a way to share data between HtmlHelpers. The goal is to set configuration once instead of passing a parameter with each call. In the example below, I'm setting the form type to determine the grid configuration:

```cs
@{ Html.SetFormType(HtmlHelpers.FormType.Boxed); }
@Html.FormItemFor(m => m.LoginName)
@Html.FormItemFor(m => m.Password)
```

```cs
public static void SetFormType(this HtmlHelper helper, FormType formType)
{
    helper.ViewBag.FormType = formType;
    helper.ViewContext.ViewBag.FormType = formType;
}
```

Setting `ViewBag` does not persist through subsequent `@Html` calls. Setting `ViewContext.ViewBag` persists, but is it safe to do so?

The existing method  `EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript` is set in an instance of the `ScopeCache` class, which in turn is added to `HttpContext.Items`. Perhaps that's also a candidate to store my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the request-based-scope object of `HttpContext.Current.Items` because `HttpContext.Current` is actually the only container that is unique and always there in a request.

Cheers

PS: don't put everything directly into the items. Just add a controller-item there and work on this.